# How to search and remove sub arrays from array if string not found in list

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to search the array and to look for keywords at the second level of the array, like `["Secondary_Volunteering__c"]` and `Referral_Source_within_CF__c`.
If those values are found then keep them, if not delete them.

I have created the following but it comes back blank.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

```
foreach($getAllCustomerCustomFields as $k => $v) {
    if(!in_array(["Secondary_Volunteering__c"], $v) && !in_array("Referral_Source_within_CF__c", $v))
        unset($getAllCustomerCustomFields[$k]);
}

foreach($getAllCustomerCustomFields as $fields){
    foreach($fields as $field){
        echo( '<strong>'.$field["FIELD_LABEL"].'</strong><br>');
        foreach ($field["CUSTOM_FIELD_OPTIONS"] as $cfield){
        echo($cfield["OPTION_VALUE"].'<br>');

        }
         echo('<br>');
    }
   
}
```

This is the PHP array.

```
array(1) {
  ["CUSTOMFIELDS"]=>
  array(46) {
    ["Secondary_Volunteering__c"]=>
    array(12) {
      ["FIELD_NAME"]=>
      string(25) "Secondary_Volunteering__c"
      ["FIELD_ORDER"]=>
      int(2)
      ["FIELD_FOR"]=>
      string(7) "CONTACT"
      ["FIELD_LABEL"]=>
      string(22) "Secondary Volunteering"
      ["FIELD_TYPE"]=>
      string(11) "MULTISELECT"
      ["FIELD_HELP_TEXT"]=>
      NULL
      ["DEFAULT_VALUE"]=>
      NULL
      ["EDITABLE"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["VISIBLE"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["CUSTOM_FIELD_OPTIONS"]=>
      array(9) {
        [0]=>
        array(3) {
          ["OPTION_ID"]=>
          int(3)
          ["OPTION_VALUE"]=>
          string(6) "Events"
          ["OPTION_DEFAULT"]=>
          bool(false)
        }
      }
      ["DEPENDENCY"]=>
      NULL
      ["JOIN_OBJECT"]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["Primary_Volunteering__c"]=>
    array(12) {
      ["FIELD_NAME"]=>
      string(23) "Primary_Volunteering__c"
      ["FIELD_ORDER"]=>
      int(3)
      ["FIELD_FOR"]=>
      string(7) "CONTACT"
      ["FIELD_LABEL"]=>
      string(20) "Primary Volunteering"
      ["FIELD_TYPE"]=>
      string(11) "MULTISELECT"
      ["FIELD_HELP_TEXT"]=>
      NULL
      ["DEFAULT_VALUE"]=>
      NULL
      ["EDITABLE"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["VISIBLE"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["CUSTOM_FIELD_OPTIONS"]=>
      array(27) {
        [0]=>
        array(3) {
          ["OPTION_ID"]=>
          int(87)
          ["OPTION_VALUE"]=>
          string(9) "Animal Me"
          ["OPTION_DEFAULT"]=>
          bool(false)
        }
      }
      ["DEPENDENCY"]=>
      NULL
      ["JOIN_OBJECT"]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["Referral_Source_within_CF__c"]=>
    array(12) {
      ["FIELD_NAME"]=>
      string(30) "Referral_Source_within_CF__c"
      ["FIELD_ORDER"]=>
      int(4)
      ["FIELD_FOR"]=>
      string(7) "CONTACT"
      ["FIELD_LABEL"]=>
      string(27) "Referral Source within CF"
      ["FIELD_TYPE"]=>
      string(11) "MULTISELECT"
      ["FIELD_HELP_TEXT"]=>
      NULL
      ["DEFAULT_VALUE"]=>
      NULL
      ["EDITABLE"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["VISIBLE"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["CUSTOM_FIELD_OPTIONS"]=>
      array(8) {
        [0]=>
        array(3) {
          ["OPTION_ID"]=>
          int(1)
          ["OPTION_VALUE"]=>
          string(11) "Sarah "
          ["OPTION_DEFAULT"]=>
          bool(false)
        }
      }
      ["DEPENDENCY"]=>
      NULL
      ["JOIN_OBJECT"]=>
      NULL
    }
```

Comment: Instead of var_dump, can you provide your php array as var_export instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it looks like [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will help you here...

```
<?php

$getAllCustomerCustomFields = array_filter($getAllCustomerCustomFields, function($key) {
    return $key == 'Secondary_Volunteering__c' || $key == 'Referral_Source_within_CF__c';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)
```

This basically filters off (reduces) all the unwanted keys of the array

Comment: Ooo, nice. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, I can now see how that works here. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding. Please don't forget to accept the answer if you are happy with it.... it gives me great satisfaction! *edit - I see you have done so - thank you!